# Submit and Reset not working for contact form

Tags: javascript, contact-form, onsubmit

I have created a simple form for contact-us section on a website. For submit button, initially I used type=submit but later came across a suggestion to change it to type=button. However the code is not working for submit as well as reset. Can someone please help to point out whats wrong in my code below.

```js
function submitForm() {

  var frm = document.getElementById('contactFormAP');
  alert('H2');
  frm.submit(); // Submit the form
  alert('H3');
  frm.reset(); // Reset form data
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form class="contactForm" action="email_form.php?do=send" method="post" role="form" id="contactFormAP">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
    <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
    <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactnumber" id="contactnumber" placeholder="Contact Number" data-rule="minlen:10" data-msg="Please enter correct contact number with country code" />
    <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
    <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
  <div id="errormessage"></div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitbtn" onclick="submitForm()">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why code when you do not have to? If you want to reset after submission, you need to return an empty form. Otherwise AJAX the form. You cannot reset the form since the page is cleared on submit

Comment: After 'frm.submit();' the script  will not execute as you are submitting the form and the page will submit the date to 'email_form.php?do=send'.

Answer (score -1):

Use the OnSubmit-Listener instead:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp